# How can i get my system to recognize webdev as a command?

Tags: flutter, dart, angular-dart

I have worked in flutter for a while and thought i would check out AngularDart with a small project.
I have got everything setup in VSCode and have run

```
'flutter pub global activate webdev'
```

with success. However when i try to run `webdev` i get `'The term webdev is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function... etc`'
My dartSDK is part of the flutter install but is fully up to date - ver 2.7. The pubspec.yaml file is also set up as required. 
My search does not turn up other devs with similar problems. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `pub global run webdev serve`
i dont think you can make it a command directly as it behaves as `php artisan serve` would behave for laravel or `python manage.py runserver` from django

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. will check it out and report back asap

Answer (score 1):

pub packages are by default storaged in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin. Add `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin` in your environment variables and it might work fine.